# React-select how to filter out already chosen values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a select component defined like this:

```
this.state.list = [{label: "test1", value:1}, {label:"test2", value:2}, {label:"test3", value:3}]
this.state.selected = [{label:"test2", value:2}]

let listMap = this.state.list
let list = this.state.list

{listMap.length !== 0 ? listMap.map((item: any, key: number) => (
 <div>    
  <Select
     id="list for data"
     options={list}
     onChange={value => selectList(value)}
     placeholder="Select Your Option"
    />
 <div/>
))
```

I want is after `test2` is selected, I want the other two drop downs to show `test1`, and `test3`.

**What I have done so far:**

```
let y = this.state.selected.map(itemY => { return itemY.value })
let x = list.filter(itemX => !yFilter.includes(itemX.value)) // [{value: 1, label:"test1"},{value: 3, label: "test3"}]
```

And then replacing `options` property as `x`.

The filters are working but,

[image]

[image]

The place holder is not updating the selected values.

**What I want to achieve**:

[image]

And for the next drop down `[1]`, be only able to select those which aren't selected:

[image]

Comment: this is obviously wrong. you shouldn't use state like that

Comment: Could you suggest a way to do it right? this.state.list will come from redux store after an api call has been made, so I just did it like this for a quick representation on the issue I’m facing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate the three react selects. As you are applying filter on one it will be applicable to all react select.The filtering will also remove in all react select. You can checkout following example.
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-5u3rh

```js
import React from "react";
import {
  render
} from "react-dom";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Select from "react-select";
import "react-select/dist/react-select.css";

class ReactSelect extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      itemtitle: "",
      multi: true,
      multiValue: "eeee...",
      options: [{
          value: "Color",
          label: "Yellow"
        },
        {
          value: "Fruit",
          label: "Apple"
        },
        {
          value: "Tool",
          label: "Spanner"
        }
      ],
      options2: [{
          value: "Color",
          label: "Yellow"
        },
        {
          value: "Fruit",
          label: "Apple"
        },
        {
          value: "Tool",
          label: "Spanner"
        }
      ]
    };
  }
  onTitleChange(e, value) {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
    this.setState({
      multiValue: e.target.value
    });
  }
  handleOnChange(obj) {
    this.setState({
      multiValue: obj
    });
    this.setState({
      options2: this.state.options2.filter(v => v.value !== obj.value)
    })
  }
  handleOnChange2(obj) {
    this.setState({
      multiValue2: obj
    });
  }
  render() {
    return ( <
      div >
      <
      Select
      // multi={this.state.multi}
      options = {
        this.state.options
      }
      onChange = {
        this.handleOnChange.bind(this)
      }
      value = {
        this.state.multiValue
      }
      isSearchable = {
        false
      }
      placeholder = "eee" /
      >
      <
      Select
      // multi={this.state.multi}
      options = {
        this.state.options2
      }
      onChange = {
        this.handleOnChange2.bind(this)
      }
      value = {
        this.state.multiValue2
      }
      isSearchable = {
        false
      }
      placeholder = "eee" /
      >
      <
      /div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < ReactSelect / > , document.body);
```

Comment: Can I dynamically create options2 based on the length of the array I’m mapping?

Comment: Yes you can clone the options1 array to options2 if you need a copy and of same length

Comment: I mean, by dynamically generating the states, because my 'options' will be coming from an api which could return any length?

Comment: As long you are using setState for options, it would work.
 this.setState({
      options2: apiData
    })

Answer (score 0):

your state should look like this

```js
state = { items : [{value: 1, label:"test1", selected:false},{value: 1, label:"test2", selected:false},{value: 3, label: "test3", selected:false}]
```

Then when an option is clicked, it sets the key "selected" to true. Afterward, only map the objects with selected false as dropdown items. Remember to use setState.